# How can I deserialize JSON to a custom type which has a property of type IEnumerable<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I'm writing a console app to retrieve JSON data from a 3rd party API. I have no control over the API data structures or functionality.

Several of the calls I make will return multiple 'pages' of data. The data is a collection of objects of a certain type e.g. User.

I have created classes in my app to match the various data types from the API.

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class FooBar
{
    [JsonProperty("foo")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bar")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

The API response is always in the same format for these calls. While the actual object types in the "data" array will differ depending on what call has been made.

```
{
 "paging":{"page":1},  
 "data":[{<object>}, {<object>}, {<object>},...]
}
```

I have created a class to try to deserialize these. The dynamic[] type for the Data property is for illustrative purposes and I am happy to change it if there is a better approach.

```
public class ApiResponseObject
{
    [JsonProperty("paging")]
    public Paging PagingInfo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public dynamic[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

And I would like to have the Data collection resolve to the appropriate type for the objects it contains. e.g.

```
string userJson = "{\"paging\":{\"page\":1},\"data\":[{\"id\":1,\"first_name\":\"Joe\",\"last_name\":\"Bloggs\"},{\"id\":2,\"first_name\":\"Jane\",\"last_name\":\"Doe\"}]}"; // json string would come from API
string foobarJson = "{\"paging\":{\"page\":1},\"data\":[{\"foo\":\"Lorem\",\"bar\":\"Ipsum\"},{\"foo\":\"Dolor\",\"bar\":\"Amet\"}]}";

var userResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseObject>(userJson);
var foobarResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseObject>(foobarJson);
```

The deserialization succeeds but the Data collection is of type JObject and cannot be cast into the correct type (User, FooBar).

I am trying to avoid having to write specific response object classes for each request if possible.

I will know what type of object I am expecting in the collection when I am requesting it so I could pass that type to the deserializer but I'm not clear on how to achieve that in this particular scenario.
Something like the below psuedo code would be ideal.

```
var userResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseObject<User>>(userJson);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any time you see `dynamic` you need to ask your self *"is there a better way"* and 99 times out 100 there is. It solves 1 problem by creating more problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the generic type T, like this :

```
public class ApiResponseObject<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("paging")]
    public Paging PagingInfo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public T[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Guilhem, this was exactly the step I was missing!